# Automatically formatting parts of a cell different colors

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to put together a Excel-based, color-coded calendar for my kids. Currently the calendar looks like below:

[image]

Eventually, I would like it so that depending on the tag of each task (ie: [S] or [B]), the tag font will be automatically colored like such:

[image]

Normally I would just use conditional formatting for this, however, this calendar is set up so that each date is a single cell. Conditional formatting would apply to the entire cell, rather than just changing the color of the tag. Is it possible to apply multiple conditional font change operations to different parts of the text in the same cell?

Comment: yes it is possible, have you anything yourself? can you share some code you have tried?

Comment: Is *26* really in the same cell as *[S] Washes dishes* ?

Comment: You could skip Excel altogether and look into something like these: https://www.fatherly.com/gear/best-family-task-apps/

Comment: Use `Instr()` to find the locations of any [S] or [B] tags, then use the `Characters` collection to apply the formatting.  Note: you can't reliably use that approach once your cell content gets longer than about 250 characters.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to define a function that gets the text you want to colorcode and the color and of course which worksheet you want to apply the colorcoding. You need to simply run the routine `Main` and the rest will be taken care of. You can edit the function to take multiple texts to color, but keeping it simple is better. You need to run `Main` once for `[S]` and once for `[B]` with the colors you like. Also, you can color the numeric values, but that one would be trickier. I am not sure how exactly you have formatted the cells on the snapshot, but it seems the dates are the first characters, so you only need to find out the first text separated by a space or a new line and then you can find out the length of the text (the date) and color it.

```
Sub Main()
    Call ColorCodeTextInCell(ActiveSheet, "[B]", RGB(20,100,255))
End Sub    

    Function ColorCodeTextInCell(WS As Worksheet, sText As String, Optional iColor As Long = vbRed)
    Dim bNewInstanceFound As Boolean
    Dim iStart As Integer
    Dim cell As Range

    bNewInstanceFound = True

    For Each cell In WS.UsedRange.Cells
        iStart = 1
        Do While bNewInstanceFound = True
            Set cell = WS.Range("A1")
            iStart = InStr(iStart, cell.Value, sText)
            If iStart > 0 Then
                cell.Characters(iStart, Len(sText)).Font.Color = iColor
                iStart = iStart + Len(sText)
            Else
                bNewInstanceFound = False
            End If
        Loop
    Next cell
End Function
```

Comment: Everything about the logic/solution seems good, but why is it a `function` and not a parameter-accepting `sub`/procedure? Asking, not challenging, maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @chillin good question, in fact it can be a sub too, but usually for error handling purposes a function is better, in this case the output of the function can be a boolean variable showing whether the procedure was executed successfully or not, you can change it to a sub since we are not getting any output from this  right now

Comment: understood, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a the ColorIndex Property of Fonts.  See the [Microsoft Docs Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.colorindex).

Below is an example of how you could do it.

```
Public Sub ColorSubTest()
    'A range to work with
    Dim rng As Range
    'Set range to A1
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

    'Reset ColorIndex to black
    rng.Font.ColorIndex = 1
    'Set the text you want for the task
    rng.Value2 = "[S] Wash Dishes"
    'Choose the color index you want 3 is red
    rng.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=3).Font.ColorIndex = 3

    'Next row
    Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
    'Reset ColorIndex to black
    rng.Font.ColorIndex = 1
    'Set the text you want for the task
    rng.Value2 = "[B] Fold Clothes"
    'Choose the color index you want 5 is blue
    rng.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=3).Font.ColorIndex = 5

End Sub
```